# Azure Logic App - Get Cookie Value from Login Request

Tags: azure, cookies, azure-logic-apps

### The following situation:

I use Postman to do a REST-API request at https://website.com/login 
I use the following body to authenticate:

```
{
    "emailAddress": "example@contoso.com",
    "password": "example",
    "rememberMe": true
}
```

This gives a status code 200 in Postman:

[image: Picture]

What I see is that in the header there is a Set-Cookie with the same value:

[image: Picture 2]

What I want is to save the Set-Cookie as a variable so I can use it for further authentication in the API. Because the first part of the API is normal basic authentication, but the other parts of the API must be authenticated by an session-cookie. I have tried to use solution: [Get cookie data from response in Logic App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71580012/get-cookie-data-from-response-in-logic-app) , but this did not work for me, because then the value must exist in the JSON. The cookie is dynamically generated.

Comment: Sorry but I don’t fully understand, what do you mean by “this did not work for me, because then the value must exist in the JSON”? What value must exist in what JSON?

Comment: As explained. When I login it will generate a 'session-cookie' this is displayed in the header in Postman because it is saved dynamically so the cookie can be used for other parts to call the API. But when I want to do the same outside Postman and do the authentication part it does not return the cookie in either the body or the header.

Comment: Ok but that doesn’t explain why my other answer (that you referenced) doesn’t work. I wasn’t asking you to explain your question again, that I understand, what I don’t understand is why the referenced answer doesn’t work. Maybe you can explain that better.

Comment: I have solved it differently, it seems that the Set-Cookie value I was able to call it in the Azure Workflow. But what I want now is that this cookie value should be saved in a custom connector so I can extract this value and use it for further authentication.

Comment: **@Leonardo van de Weteringh**, Great to hear that. Could you post your solution into the answer section here. It would help other community members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue by doing the following:

- Create 3 cards.

1. HTTP Request that does the actual request
2. A variable initializer that saves the header into an object variable
3. A variable initalizer with the following expression, saved as a string type:

```
split(variables('Headers')?['Set-Cookie'],';')[0]
```

Hopefully this helps you guys implement cookie-based authentication further into your workflows.